# Xamarin.forms custom font exception

Tags: c#, ios, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Hello I am trying to apply a custom font to a Label using the following code

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="ExerClub.Pages.Profile" Title="Profile">
  <StackLayout>
    <Label Text="Login">
      <Label.FontFamily>
        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:String">
          <OnPlatform.iOS>MarkerFelt-Thin</OnPlatform.iOS>
          <OnPlatform.Android></OnPlatform.Android>
          <OnPlatform.WinPhone></OnPlatform.WinPhone>
        </OnPlatform>
      </Label.FontFamily>
    </Label>
    <Label Text="Club Name"/>
    <Label Text="More randomness"/>

  </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

Code Behind

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace ExerClub.Pages
{
    public partial class Profile : ContentPage
    {
        public Profile()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

This is taken from [Xamarin.forms Documentation](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/text/fonts/#Using_a_Custom_Font)

I am getting the following error on iOS

```
System.ArgumentException: Object of type 'System.String' cannot be converted to type 'Xamarin.Forms.View'.
```

I am new to Xamarin and don't really understand why this might fail.

Comment: Could you please show the full page? Unless I am overlooking something, the error doesn't seem to come from here.

Comment: I added the code behind as well. I didn't really change anything there are the tutorial didn't mention anything either.

Comment: Are you using the latest version of Xamarin.Forms from NuGet? If not, update and Rebuild.

Comment: I'm such a noob. I finally found the problem. The issue was a randome `/>` sitting in another xaml page that loaded before this. This page is actually a detail page on a master detail page so It didn't really click in my mind to check the master.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put font name `<x:String>fontName</x:String>` tags or simply write like below:

```
<Label Text="Login">
  <Label.FontFamily>
  <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:String"
              iOS="MarkerFelt-Thin" Android=""
              WinPhone=""/>
  </Label.FontFamily>
</Label>
```

Comment: This  was not exactly the solution. The problem was a silly mistake on my part but thumbs up for the vastly easier and more convenient way of doing this. The official documentation was so convoluted.